# Get status of activity manager

Tags: android, python, bash, android-emulator, adb

I'm writing a python script that makes calls to adb to perform JUnit tests.  I've used 'adb get-state' and 'adb wait-for-device' to wait for when the emulator is booted and ready to go, but for some reason, both of these kick off too early.  After these functions return, I get this error when I start to run my tests:

```
android.util.AndroidException: Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?
```

Is there a way I can get the status of the activity manager?  If I could just poll that status that should be sufficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adb wait-for-device tells you if the adbd on the device is responsive. However, that it a linux-level daemon on the device, well below the level of the android platform which is normally started after (except in the case where ADB has just been enabled from the settings menu).

Particularly on emulators, starting up the java-level android runtime is a lengthy process, so there can be a period of seconds to minutes when adbd is responsive, but there is no ActivityManager to talk to.

After adb wait-for-server, putting an attempt to do whatever you are trying to do (presumably run the 'am' command) in a loop with a one second delay and checking the output may be the simplest solution.

Comment: Sorry for the double question, but it got your attention :)  This is what I ended up doing as a work around.  I just wanted to find a more for sure way to get this to work (as the time to loop before I give up can be quite variable).