# adb wait-for-device is a dirty liar

Tags: android, macos, bash, osx-lion, adb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get status of activity manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316354/get-status-of-activity-manager)

I'm writing a script that boots up the android emulator and performs uninstall and install operations.  I'd like to use `adb wait-for-device` as a way to hold off until the emulator is ready to go.

Unfortunately, it looks like it jumps the gun.  It will stop waiting (sometimes) too early, and then when the script tries to uninstall and reinstall the app, I get the error message:

```
Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
```

and

```
android.util.AndroidException: Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?
```

Sometimes adb will just hang.  Never picking up the emulator, but this happens slightly less often then going to early.  I get the same behavior with `adb get-state`.

I'm running on OSX Lion if thats any help.

Comment: Do not ask duplicate questions!  Moving answer to the original and voting to close this.

Comment: Reposted mostly because I forgot I asked a few days ago. @netcoder